# Problem installing android studio

Tags: linux-mint, android

I'm getting the following java error while trying to install android studio in linuxmint 18.3:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f24a317ca66, pid=26317, tid=0x00007f24aa23f700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_161-b12) (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.161-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x13a66]  readCEN+0xb46
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/void/java_error_in_STUDIO_26317.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I followed these steps:

1. Installing Java

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
2. Download Android Studio from here, use All Android Studio Packages
3. Execute ./studio.sh

Answer (score 0):

Your java/android studio installation doesn't seem right to me. Unless you're on a very special CPU architecture, I would not use `apt` to install java (unless your okay with openjdk). I would download the .tar.gz (make sure to pick the JDK not the JRE) image straight from oracle, unpack it to `/opt` (or anywhere else is okay too) and create sym-links to `/usr/bin` for `java` `javac` and `javaw`.

If I'm not mistaken, android studio also offers a version with java included inside the download. You could try that version as well without java installed.

You could also try the openjdks version of java. That might work.

I have android studio running with the .tar.gz from oracle installed as described above, never ran into issues.

However i think in your case try redownloading android studio (perhaps pick a different download?) first.